# how to set the findAll() on springboot to only return one column of it's foreign key's table

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I'm working on a database with multiple relations, how can I return only the table I need and some of its columns instead of what findAll() returns which is the table the related table and tables related to that one and so on.

What I'm getting is something along the lines of:

```json
{
    "id":1 ,
    "title": "foo",
    "writer": {
       "id":6,
       "name": "name",
       "group": {
         "id":3,
         "name":"group"
       }
    }
}
```

how can i get something like this:

```json
{
  "id":1 ,
  "title": "foo",
  "writer": {
    "name": "name",
   }
}
```

Should I use jpql? Otherwise, what's the best approach.

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: i'm using mysql for now but i'm going to be moving to oracle 12c at a later date.

Comment: You could query a view that only has the information you need, or use a specific query via jpql, or even use GraphQL

Comment: I don't exactly know how to do the first two and i didn't know graphql was compatible with springboot regardless I am building a restful server .

Comment: Is it ok to retrieve everything from the database and the expose exactly what you want in your REST API?

Comment: @wael: You can also return a DTO instead of your entity and have that DTO hold only the fields you need, then all you need to do is convert your entity to the DTO, a simple matter of mapping fields from the entity to the DTO

Comment: @JoãoDias:  I don't think that would be a good practice even thought it is possible

Comment: @JustAnotherDeveloper that sounds like a good approach do you happen to know any good resource to get to learn dto in springboot as clear as it seems i am still new to this.

Comment: @wael DTO is not Spring Boot specific. Just learn about DTO in general, there should be plenty of resources if you just search "DTO".

Comment: alright, thank you kindly

Comment: @wael, I was asking because if it is, then you could follow this DTO approach, that you in fact should be using. Using entities in your REST API is definitely not a good practice and something that you should avoid, as you just learned.

Comment: yea I noticed seems rather essential at this point, i can't be going without them, I may not know much but i can tell this would cause a lot of problems later on

Comment: Why do you say that? What kind of problems are you thinking about?

Comment: latency issues and possible crashes that kind of stuff that can happen with large databases with a lot of relations

Comment: Well, then you will have to implement some custom SQL queries.

Answer (score 0):

One possibility would be relying on JPQL for this. Assuming that your entity class is called `Article` it would be something in the line of:

```java
@Query("select article.id, article.title from Article article")
List<Article> getAllArticlesOptimized();
```

You can read more about this at https://www.appsdeveloperblog.com/specific-columns-jpa-native-query/.

---

Another possibility would be [Projections](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#projections) so that you can selectively retrieve partial views of your entities. You would declare an interface that exposes accessor methods for the properties to be read:

```java
interface ArticleSummary {

  Long getId();
  String getTitle();
  WriterSummary getWriter();

  interface WriterSummary {
    String getName();
  }
}
```

And you would use it as the return type in your repository:

```java
interface ArticleRepository extends Repository<Article, Long> {
  List<ArticleSummary> findAll();
}
```

Comment: @wael, did this help? Let me know if something is unclear.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [native-query and `ResultTransformer`](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#sql-dto-query):

```java
    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    @Override
    public Optional<ArticleDTO> getArticle(final long id) {
        final Session sess = entityManager.unwrap(Session.class);
        return sess.createNativeQuery(
            "select a.id, a.title, w.name from Article a left outer join Writer w on a.writer_id = w.id where a.id = :id")
            .setParameter("id", id)
            .addScalar("id", LongType.INSTANCE)
            .addScalar("name", StringType.INSTANCE)
            .addScalar("title", StringType.INSTANCE)
            .setResultTransformer(new ArticleResultTransformer())
            .uniqueResultOptional();
    }

    public static class ArticleResultTransformer extends BasicTransformerAdapter {
        @Override
        public Object transformTuple(final Object[] tuple, final String[] aliases) {
            final Optional<String> writerName = Optional.ofNullable((String) tuple[2]);
            final WriterDTO writer = writerName.map(name -> new WriterDTO(name)).orElse(null);

            return new ArticleDTO((Long) tuple[0], (String) tuple[1], writer);
        }
    }
```

[See also](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#best-practices-fetching):

> Hibernate supports both entity queries (JPQL/HQL and Criteria API) and native SQL statements. Entity queries are useful only if you need to modify the fetched entities, therefore benefiting from the automatic dirty checking mechanism.
>
> For read-only transactions, you should fetch DTO projections because they allow you to select just as many columns as you need to fulfill a certain business use case. This has many benefits like reducing the load on the currently running Persistence Context because DTO projections don’t need to be managed.